# How to split 2 items of an array and join into one item?

Tags: python, arrays

I've made a Python program with array that has 2 items. I want to split and join those 2 items into one item. So the result should be 'first item, second item'. It gives that error AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. I attached the code.

```
items_in_cart=['first item','second item']
a,b=items_in_cart.split(", ")
items_in_cart=a+b
print(items_in_cart)
```

Comment: You can not split a list. Either you have to convert it in to a string or just use `items_in_cart=items_in_cart[0]+items_in_cart[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
', '.join(items_in_cart)
```

Your list already has items *split*. You want to *join* them together again.